# Weak convergence on L^p

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Let Let $X=[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure, find a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of measurable functions $f_n:X \rightarrow{ \mathbb{R} }   $ such that:

1. $f_n(x)\rightarrow{0}$ almost everywhere $x∈[0,1]$
2. $f_n$ converge to $0$ in measure.
3. $f_n$ not converge weakly to $0$ in $L^p([0,1])$ for any $p$, $1≤p< \infty$

Comment: What is a necessary condition for a sequence to be weakly convergent?

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$
f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
n^2&\text{for $0\leq x\leq\frac1n$},\\
0&\text{for $\frac1n< x\leq1$}.
\end{cases}
$$
The sequence is unbounded, hence not weakly convergent, but convergent in the sense of 1 and 2.

Comment: Of note: One can verify that the sequence does not converge weakly to $0$ directly. Integrate against $\chi_{[0,1]}\in L_P^*$.